# Java regex case insensitivity not working

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to remove some words in a string using regex using below program. Its removing properly but its considering only case sensitive. How to make it as case insensitive. I kept `(?1)` in `replaceAll` method but it didn't work.

```
package com.test.java;

public class RemoveWords {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        // assign some words to string

        String sample ="what Is the latest news today in Europe? is there any thing special or everything is common.";

            System.out.print(sample.replaceAll("( is | the |in | any )(?i)"," "));
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
what Is latest news today  Europe? there thing special or everything common.
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to place the `(?i)` **before** the part of the pattern that you want to make case insensitive:

```
System.out.print(sample.replaceAll("(?i)\\b(?:is|the|in|any)\\b"," "));
                                    ^^^^
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/zJui9)

I've replaced spaces around the keywords to be removed with word boundary (`\\b`). The problem comes because there may be two keywords one after another separated by just one space.

If you want to delete the keywords only if they are surrounded by **space**, then you can use positive lookahead and lookbehind as:

```
(?i)(?<= )(is|the|in|any)(?= )
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/9kcKm)

Comment: "the" exists in the output. it didn't replace with " " and it doesn't remove "IS" see it http://www.ideone.com/HMxLr

Comment: Correct. Why it's not replacing "the" with " " . Any problem with the regex

Comment: @codaddict: Note that this leaves multiple spaces in a row, which is possibly not ideal but may be tricky to avoid.

Comment: @codaddict works but I don't understand anything from this regex. Anyway, I revert my -1

Comment: @Jon: You are right. But adding a `.replaceAll(" +"," ")` will solve that. Doing all this in a single regex will be tricky.

Comment: @hilal: `(?i)(?<= )(is|the|in|any)(?= )`: This will match either a `is` or a `the` or a `in` or a `any` **if** they have space surrounding them.

Comment: @codaddict: Yes... I thought it was sufficiently tricky that I deleted my answer and decided to leave it to you :)

Comment: @codaddict It's working perfectly. Can you explain bit more about (?<= ) and (?= )

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can specify case insensitive with the quick replace.
Try a pattern instead. i.e:

```
package com.test.java;

public class RemoveWords {

public static void main(String args[]) {
  // assaign some words to string
  String sample ="what Is the latest news today in Europe? is there any thing special or everything is common.";
  String regex = "( is | the |in | any )"
  System.out.print
  (
    Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(sample).replaceAll("")
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but as @codaddicts answer shows, you *can* use those flags in `String.replaceAll()`.

Comment: @Joachim: No worries. I upvoted @Codaddicts answer since I got to know how to use flags in String.replaceAll

Answer (score 1):

change `is` to `[iI][sS]`

```
sample.replaceAll("( [iI][sS] ...
```

Comment: It works but lengthy process where we need to put every character. Is there any better way