# Java regex to remove NULL string

Tags: java, regex, null

I want to replace the following string with Blank String (`""`) if it is equal to `“NULL”,“null”, “Null”, “nuLl”, “(null)”, “[null]”, {null}` etc. I am finding it difficult to cater all the scenarios with the below regex

```
^NULL$
```

So if the input is `“a null b”` the output will be `“a null b”`

But if the input is `“null”` output will be `“”`

Comment: And what the expected output for `a null b`? I would expect `ab`.

Comment: use [CASE_INSENSITIVE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) and take out ^ $

Comment: “a null b” the output has to be “a null b”

Comment: Try with "(?i)null" as regular expression. Please see my below answer for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can truy with this pattern: `(?i)[(\\[{]?null[)\\]}]?`.
Please, see below example:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class EnumProgram {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        test("a NULL b", "a  b");
        test("a null b", "a  b");
        test("a Null b", "a  b");
        test("a NuLl b", "a  b");
        test("a (null) b", "a  b");
        test("a [null] b", "a  b");
        test("a {null} b", "a  b");
    }

    private static void test(String value, String expected) {
        String newValue = Util.removeNullString(value);
        System.out.println(value + " : " + newValue.equals(expected));
    }
}

class Util {
    private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)[(\\[{]?null[)\\]}]?");

    public static String removeNullString(String value) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
            return StringUtils.EMPTY;
        }

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
        return matcher.replaceAll(StringUtils.EMPTY);
    }
}
```

Comment: try with (?i) in regular expression as in my below answer

Comment: regex is very close to what I was expecting... Thanks

Comment: so matching stuff like {null] was actually ok? This would actually match also (null

Comment: {null] is matching. but there is a catch as micantox mentioned... It is also matching (null or null) - which should not be the case

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is called a "case-insensitive" regular expression. Not being a Java expert, I found this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813497/java-regex-case-insensitivity-not-working) which has the following line, edited to fit your needs:

```
System.out.print(sample.replaceAll("(?i)\\b(?:null)\\b",""));
```

Comment: What about `(null)`, `[null]` and `{null}`?

Comment: Thank,.. but this will not match (null)

Comment: I didn't see this requirement in the original post. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str.replaceAll("(?i)\\(null\\)|\\[null\\]|\\{null\\}|null", "");
```

Comment: Eww. Ever heard of [case-insensitive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) matching? And this will also match `[null)`, though I don't believe it should.

Comment: A kitten is killed every time you use this regex

Answer (score 0):

Use (?i) to validate case insensitive in regular expression. See the below code for example. The below code will output "a b"

```
String str = "a NULl b";
String regx = "(?i)null";
String str2 = str.replaceAll(regx, "");
System.out.println(str2);

output : a b
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
private static String removeNull(String input)
    {
        String[] splittedValue = input.split(" ");
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String value : splittedValue)
        {
            if (!value.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
            {
                stringBuilder.append(value);
                stringBuilder.append(" ");
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Comment: At first look this won't work. What about `blabla {null} bla`?

Comment: What about `(null)`, `[null]` and `{null}`?