# Find string that does not contain some substring

Tags: java, regex

I have a one liner string that looks like this:

> My db objects are db.main_flow_tbl, 'main_flow_audit_tbl',
>   main_request_seq and MAIN_SUBFLOW_TBL.

I want to use regular expressions to return database tables that start with **main** but do not contain words **audit** or **seq**, and irrespective of the case. So in the above example strings *main_flow_tbl* and *MAIN_SUBFLOW_TBL* shall return. Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Maybe this links could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813497/java-regex-case-insensitivity-not-working and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word

Comment: What did you try so far? Does it need to use a regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fully regex based solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String in = "My db objects are db.main_flow_tbl, 'main_flow_audit_tbl', main_request_seq and MAIN_SUBFLOW_TBL.";
    final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("main_(?!\\w*?(?:audit|seq))\\w++", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    final Matcher m = pat.matcher(in);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
main_flow_tbl
MAIN_SUBFLOW_TBL
```

This assumes that table names can only contain `A-Za-Z_` which `\w` is the shorthand for.

Pattern breakdown:

- `main_` is the liternal "main" that you want tables to start with
- `(?!\\w*?(?:audit|seq))` is a negative lookahead (not followed by) which takes any number of `\w` characters (lazily) followed by either "audit" or "seq". This excludes tables names that contain those sequences.
- `\\w++` consume any table characters possesively.

**EDIT**

OP's comment *they may contain numbers as well*

In this case use this pattern:

```
main_(?![\\d\\w]*?(?:audit|seq))[\\d\\w]++
```

i.e. use `[\\d\\w]` rather than `\\w`

Comment: they may contain numbers as well

Comment: Nice solution! I was still tossing around on the negative lookahead

Comment: Can you please explain it to me to get the maximum benefit?

Comment: @YasserAlMasri There is a breakdown of the pattern, what parts do you need me to expand?

Comment: my particular question is that I tried this:
(?i)main_(?!.*audit|seq)[a-zA-Z0-9_]*
but it kept eliminating all the line once audit or seq is found. What's the difference that made yours do the trick?

Comment: @YasserAlMasri two things. 1) I used `[\\d\\w]*?` rather than `.*`, this matches only inside the table name - otherwise it will wander along until it finds an `audit` or `seq` _anywhere_ further in the `String`. It is also lazy rather than greedy. 2) I used `(?:audit|seq)` - i.e. I encapsulated the or in a non-capturing group; your pattern `.*audit|seq` is actually `.*audit` or `seq`.

Comment: Appreciated. This is a real regex guru!

Answer (score 0):

```
String str
while ((str.startsWith("main"))&&!str.contains("audit")||!str.contains("seq")){
   //your code here
}
```

Comment: I asked for regular expressions

Comment: @YasserAlMasri: Is this homework? Why does it have to be a regular expression if there is a working alternative?

Comment: because it will be very tedious otherwise. What is str in your case? I don't have anything to capture an array of strings that really contain the tables. It just can be anything with in the string

Answer (score 0):

If the string matches

```
    ^main_(\w_)*(?!(?:audit|seq))
```

it should be what you want...

Comment: Almost. You don't have the case insensitive flag. You have a start anchor so it won't find patterns _in_ `String`s; which is what the OP wants. And your match group would capture _up to_ the sequences the OP doesn't want. So rather than excluding names containing `seq` like `table_seq` this would capture `table_`. In short **test your code before posting**.